# java.sql.SQLException: connect error when connecting to TDengine database

Tags: jdbc, druid, tdengine

I'm trying Druid to connect TDengine.

url jdbc:TAOS-RS://127.0.0.1:6041/test?user=xxx&password=xxxx

Then I got the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: connect error
```

If I use JDBC directly, it's ok. What may be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have launched taosAdapter.

You can try

```
systemctl start taosadapter
```